# Software for Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, universal-algebra

Is there any software that is designed specifically for algebraic structures, that can do some of the basic constructions in algebra, like

- Constructing the congruence lattice of a (finite) algebra, the lattices of sub-algebras, maximal sub-algebras, the sub-algebra generated by a set, quotients, ect.

  - Testing whether a set of term equations $E$ deduces another set of equations $E'$. Or finding a counter example, ect.
  - Basic constructions for (finite, commutative) rings, like the Jacobson radical ideal, or the nil-potent radical ideal, or testing whether a subring is integral.
  - Various constructions on groups, like the Jordon-Holder decomposition, the center, sylow subgroups, ect.

Comment: +1 for the soft-question pun. Also, have you looked at Sage, PARI, and GAP? (The first contains the other two IIRC. Certainly GAP.)

Comment: I havent, but Ill check them out. I have only seen prover 9, but that doesnt seem like it is what I describe above

Comment: Yeah you're looking more for a "computer algebra system" than an automated prover it sounds like. Take a look at Sage first. I've never attempted a few of the calculations you mentioned in a CAS (computing Jacobson and nil radicals, for instance), but if a halting algorithm is known for computing some kind of algebraic object, it is (or probably can be efficiently) implemented in Sage. As such you probably won't find generic <Claim about Objects> --> <Counterexample> functionality in a CAS, but you can still use them to find counterexamples by testing hypotheses on huge sample sets.

Comment: Here's a link to a tutorial on Sage's group theory capabilities: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/group_theory.html

Comment: Also look at the universal algebra calculator: http://www.uacalc.org/

Comment: Also, here's a better link for how you can work with Sylow subgroups in Sage: http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/sylow-sage.html

Comment: Thanks! The last three links are great, especially the UACaculator

Comment: For (dis)proving equations, [Prover9/Mace4](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/). Perhaps it is also bundled in Sage.

Comment: See also [this MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74804).